# Spring Boot Mongo pull elements from nested array of documents

Tags: java, mongodb, mongotemplate

I'm trying to pull a value of a sub array using springboot mongotemplate custom update.

this is sample document.

```
"email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@demo.com",
"t_maps": [
  {
    "app_name": "2321321",
    "app_id": [
      "E-123456789",
      "A-123456789"
    ]
  },
  {
    "app_name": "23231",
    "app_id": [
      "E-123456789",
      "A-123456789"
    ]
  },
  {
    "app_name": "abcd 121",
    "app_id": [
     "E-123456789",
      "A-123456789"
    ]
  }
]
```

I am able to pull a value from sub array **engagements** in mongo shell by using below query.

```
db.user_maps_id.update({email: {"$in": ["yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy@demo.com","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@demo.com"]}},
{$pull: {"t_maps.$[].app_id": "A-123456789"}}, {multi: true})
```

when i am doing with code, i am not able to pull value, getting matched count is 2 but where as modified count is 0. i am not able to pull a value from sub-array.
please correct me where i am doing wrong.

the code is shared below:
Custom Repository

```
public interface CustomUserMapsIdRepository {
void updateUserMapsIdRepository(List<CustomUserMapsId> userMapsIdRepository, String app_id); }
```

The implementation class:

```
@Component
public class CustomUserMapsIdRepositoryImpl implements CustomUserMapsIdRepository {
@Autowired
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@Override
public void updateUserMapsIdRepository(List<CustomUserMapsId> userMapsIdRepository, String app_id) {
    
    List<String> emails = userMapsIdRepository.parallelStream().map(i -> i.getEmail()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("email").in(emails));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.pull("t_maps.$[].app_id", app_id);
    
    UpdateResult result = mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, UserToolEngagements.class);
    
    BulkWriteResult execute = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.ORDERED, UserToolEngagements.class).updateMulti(query, update).execute();
    int matchedCount = execute.getMatchedCount();
    System.out.println("matchedCount = " + matchedCount);
    int modifiedCount = execute.getModifiedCount();
    System.out.println("modifiedCount = " + modifiedCount);
}}
```

Thank you so much ton times in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution where as i was removed below code

```
 public interface CustomUserMapsIdRepository {
 void updateUserMapsIdRepository(List<CustomUserMapsId> userMapsIdRepository, 
  String app_id); }
```

by using below code i am able to pull element from sub array: **app_id**

```
mongoTemplate.updateMulti(Query.query(Criteria.where("t_maps.app_id").is(app_id)), new Update().pull("t_maps.$[].app_id", engagement), XXXX.class).getModifiedCount() > 0;
```